# Angular 9 SSR refresh/reload

Tags: angular, angular9

I have the following problem with **Angular** and **SSR**. I use **angular 9**. Everything works fine but when
I click **F5** the first thing which I see is the login page of my application and after that I see the page I'm on. I built the application with **angular 8** and everything worked fine. 
Now I decided to migrate to the next version.

Any suggestion?

Comment: have you tried disabling IVY?

Answer (score 1):

That is the issue of your token you might have used localstorage for storing token and your backend won't able to get the token from it so it is showing login screen first and then on angular side it is giving actual page for this you need to use cookie instead of localstorage to resolve this issue or even easier you can use loader till platform browser detection completed and rest of the things will work in same manner.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue too.

So, I try to remove and add an angular universal again. It shows that some structures has changed.
https://v9.angular.io/guide/universal

And also, I'm not sure about how Ivy work with SSR so I disabled it by adding an option in tsconfig.app.json followed this https://v9.angular.io/guide/ivy

And then it works.